# Simple Interpreted Language Design & Implementation

Tags: vm-implementation, interpreted-language

I need some resources for implementing a simple virtual machine and interpreted language.  Something that is pratical is most useful.  I have read the Virtual Machine Implementation book and found that it is quite old and doesn't represent the vms I see today.  Also if someone know of a fairly simplistic language that would be great as well.

Answer (score 2):

check [The implementation of Lua 5.0](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/doc/jucs05.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You don't say if this is for a new project, to work with an existing project, for learning, or what target environment, language, and OS you're using.

If you want to learn about implementing your own VM and scripting language, get the book [Game Scripting Mastery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1931841578). Despite its title, it is actually about implementing your own virtual machine and scripting language. The source code is for Win32, but the concepts can be applied to .Net or Linux.

As a bonus, when you're done you will have a playable, scriptable, 2D adventure game.